# Ignore parentheses in MYSQL Like query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like

I have a sample MYSQL table with the following rows:

```
name
------
Oppo A71 (2018)
Plum Flipper (2018)
Lenovo K5 Note (2018)
Huawei Y9 (2018)
Huawei Y7 (2018)
```

I want to let the user search through the database. The problem is that in most cases, a user would search for the keyword `2018` without the parentheses like `samsung a8 2018` for example instead of `samsung a8 (2018)`.

So for the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM phones WHERE name LIKE '% 2018 %'
```

It will return nothing because `2018` is stored in the db with brackets around it.

If I switch the query to:

```
SELECT * FROM phones WHERE name LIKE '%2018%'
```

It will display the results correctly but I don't want the query to match the text if it's part of the string or that would return thousands of irrelevant rows. The words must be actually words found not part of words. So I must have spaces around the year.

Is there a way when running `LIKE` to ignore the brackets so that `2018` for example matches rows with `(2018)` as word?

Comment: Something else to consider: If the "2018" is separate information (e.g. the product's construction year), it should be stored as a separate attribute. Not only will this remove the issue with your query, but make it adhere to basic relational principles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One method is regular expressions.  But with `like`, you can replace the parens before matching:

```
SELECT *
FROM phones
WHERE REPLACE(REPLACE(name, '(', ' '), ')', ' ') LIKE '% 2018 %'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can check two conditions combined with `OR` to check for both situations. Try:

```
SELECT * FROM phones 
WHERE name LIKE '% 2018 %' OR
      name LIKE '%(2018)%'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression to just look for 2018 as a word by itself. Just use the word boundary elements around it:

```
SELECT *
FROM phones
WHERE name REGEXP '[[:<:]]2018[[:>:]]'
```

Answer (score 1):

While answer provided by Gordon Linoff will certainly work, it's not going to perform well when your datasets grow, a way better approach is to use full text search on your table which should deal with these kind of issues way easier.